# how to make pandas HDFStore 'put' operation faster

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to build a ETL toolkit with pandas, hdf5.

My plan was

1. extracting a table from mysql to a DataFrame;
2. put this DataFrame into a HDFStore;

But when i was doing the step 2, i found putting a dataframe into a *.h5 file costs too much time.

- the size of table in source mysql server: 498MB

  - 52 columns
  - 924,624 records
- the size of *.h5 file after putting the dataframe inside : 513MB

  - the 'put' operation costs 849.345677137 seconds

My questions are:
Is this time costs normal?
Is there any way to make it faster?

---

### Update 1

thanks Jeff

- my codes are pretty simple:

  extract_store = HDFStore('extract_store.h5')
  extract_store['df_staff'] = df_staff
- and when i trying 'ptdump -av file.h5', i got an error, but i still could load the dataframe object from this h5 file:

> tables.exceptions.HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace
>
> File "../../../src/H5F.c", line 1512, in H5Fopen
>       unable to open file   File "../../../src/H5F.c", line 1307, in H5F_open
>       unable to read superblock   File "../../../src/H5Fsuper.c", line 305, in H5F_super_read
>       unable to find file signature   File "../../../src/H5Fsuper.c", line 153, in H5F_locate_signature
>       unable to find a valid file signature
>
> End of HDF5 error back trace
>
> Unable to open/create file 'extract_store.h5'

- some other infos:

  - pandas version: '0.10.0'
  - os: ubuntu server 10.04 x86_64
  - cpu: 8 * Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5670  @ 2.93GHz
  - MemTotal: 51634016 kB

I will update the pandas to 0.10.1-dev and try again.

---

### Update 2

- I had updated pandas to '0.10.1.dev-6e2b6ea'
- but the time costs wasn't decreased, it costs 884.15 s seconds this time
- the output of 'ptdump -av file.h5 ' is :

```
    / (RootGroup) ''  
      /._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 4 attributes:  
       [CLASS := 'GROUP',  
        PYTABLES_FORMAT_VERSION := '2.0',  
        TITLE := '',  
        VERSION := '1.0']  
    /df_bugs (Group) ''  
      /df_bugs._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 12 attributes:  
       [CLASS := 'GROUP',  
        TITLE := '',  
        VERSION := '1.0',  
        axis0_variety := 'regular',  
        axis1_variety := 'regular',  
        block0_items_variety := 'regular',  
        block1_items_variety := 'regular',  
        block2_items_variety := 'regular',  
        nblocks := 3,  
        ndim := 2,  
        pandas_type := 'frame',  
        pandas_version := '0.10.1']  
    /df_bugs/axis0 (Array(52,)) ''  
      atom := StringAtom(itemsize=19, shape=(), dflt='')  
      maindim := 0  
      flavor := 'numpy'  
      byteorder := 'irrelevant'  
      chunkshape := None  
      /df_bugs/axis0._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 7 attributes:  
       [CLASS := 'ARRAY',  
        FLAVOR := 'numpy',  
        TITLE := '',  
        VERSION := '2.3',  
        kind := 'string',  
        name := None,  
        transposed := True]  
    /df_bugs/axis1 (Array(924624,)) ''  
      atom := Int64Atom(shape=(), dflt=0)  
      maindim := 0  
      flavor := 'numpy'  
      byteorder := 'little'  
      chunkshape := None  
      /df_bugs/axis1._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 7 attributes:  
       [CLASS := 'ARRAY',  
        FLAVOR := 'numpy',  
        TITLE := '',  
        VERSION := '2.3',  
        kind := 'integer',  
        name := None,  
        transposed := True]  
    /df_bugs/block0_items (Array(5,)) ''  
      atom := StringAtom(itemsize=12, shape=(), dflt='')  
      maindim := 0   
      flavor := 'numpy'  
      byteorder := 'irrelevant'  
      chunkshape := None  
      /df_bugs/block0_items._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 7 attributes:  
       [CLASS := 'ARRAY',  
        FLAVOR := 'numpy',  
        TITLE := '',  
        VERSION := '2.3',  
        kind := 'string',  
        name := None,  
        transposed := True]  
    /df_bugs/block0_values (Array(924624, 5)) ''  
      atom := Float64Atom(shape=(), dflt=0.0)  
      maindim := 0  
      flavor := 'numpy'  
      byteorder := 'little'  
      chunkshape := None  
      /df_bugs/block0_values._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 5 attributes:  
       [CLASS := 'ARRAY',  
        FLAVOR := 'numpy',  
        TITLE := '',  
        VERSION := '2.3',  
        transposed := True]  
    /df_bugs/block1_items (Array(19,)) ''  
      atom := StringAtom(itemsize=19, shape=(), dflt='')  
      maindim := 0  
      flavor := 'numpy'  
      byteorder := 'irrelevant'  
      chunkshape := None  
      /df_bugs/block1_items._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 7 attributes:  
       [CLASS := 'ARRAY',  
        FLAVOR := 'numpy',  
        TITLE := '',  
        VERSION := '2.3',  
        kind := 'string',  
        name := None,  
        transposed := True]  
    /df_bugs/block1_values (Array(924624, 19)) ''  
      atom := Int64Atom(shape=(), dflt=0)  
      maindim := 0  
      flavor := 'numpy'  
      byteorder := 'little'  
      chunkshape := None  
      /df_bugs/block1_values._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 5 attributes:  
       [CLASS := 'ARRAY',  
        FLAVOR := 'numpy',  
        TITLE := '',   
        VERSION := '2.3',  
        transposed := True]  
    /df_bugs/block2_items (Array(28,)) ''  
      atom := StringAtom(itemsize=18, shape=(), dflt='')  
      maindim := 0  
      flavor := 'numpy'  
      byteorder := 'irrelevant'  
      chunkshape := None  
      /df_bugs/block2_items._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 7 attributes:  
       [CLASS := 'ARRAY',  
        FLAVOR := 'numpy',  
        TITLE := '',  
        VERSION := '2.3',
        kind := 'string',  
        name := None,  
        transposed := True]  
    /df_bugs/block2_values (VLArray(1,)) ''  
      atom = ObjectAtom()  
      byteorder = 'irrelevant'  
      nrows = 1  
      flavor = 'numpy'  
      /df_bugs/block2_values._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 5 attributes:  
       [CLASS := 'VLARRAY',  
        PSEUDOATOM := 'object',  
        TITLE := '',   
        VERSION := '1.3',  
        transposed := True]
```

- and I had tried your code below (putting the dataframe into hdfstore with the param 'table' is True) , but got an error instead, it seemed like python's datatime type was not supported :

> Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->object] object
>   of type 'datetime.datetime' has no len()

---

### Update 3

thanks jeff. 
Sorry for the delay.

- tables.**version** : '2.4.0'.
- yes, the 884 seconds is only the put operation costs without the pull operation from mysql
- a row of dataframe (df.ix[0]):

```
bug_id                                   1
assigned_to                            185
bug_file_loc                          None
bug_severity                      critical
bug_status                          closed
creation_ts            1998-05-06 21:27:00
delta_ts               2012-05-09 14:41:41
short_desc                    Two cursors.
host_op_sys                        Unknown
guest_op_sys                       Unknown
priority                                P3
rep_platform                          IA32
reporter                                56
product_id                               7
category_id                            983
component_id                         12925
resolution                           fixed
target_milestone                       ws1
qa_contact                             412
status_whiteboard                         
votes                                    0
keywords                                SR
lastdiffed             2012-05-09 14:41:41
everconfirmed                            1
reporter_accessible                      1
cclist_accessible                        1
estimated_time                        0.00
remaining_time                        0.00
deadline                              None
alias                                 None
found_in_product_id                      0
found_in_version_id                      0
found_in_phase_id                        0
cf_type                             Defect
cf_reported_by                 Development
cf_attempted                           NaN
cf_failed                              NaN
cf_public_summary                         
cf_doc_impact                            0
cf_security                              0
cf_build                               NaN
cf_branch                                 
cf_change                              NaN
cf_test_id                             NaN
cf_regression                      Unknown
cf_reviewer                              0
cf_on_hold                               0
cf_public_severity                     ---
cf_i18n_impact                           0
cf_eta                                None
cf_bug_source                          ---
cf_viss                               None
Name: 0, Length: 52
```

- the picture of dataframe( just type 'df' in ipython notebook):

```
Int64Index: 924624 entries, 0 to 924623
Data columns:
bug_id                 924624  non-null values
assigned_to            924624  non-null values
bug_file_loc           427318  non-null values
bug_severity           924624  non-null values
bug_status             924624  non-null values
creation_ts            924624  non-null values
delta_ts               924624  non-null values
short_desc             924624  non-null values
host_op_sys            924624  non-null values
guest_op_sys           924624  non-null values
priority               924624  non-null values
rep_platform           924624  non-null values
reporter               924624  non-null values
product_id             924624  non-null values
category_id            924624  non-null values
component_id           924624  non-null values
resolution             924624  non-null values
target_milestone       924624  non-null values
qa_contact             924624  non-null values
status_whiteboard      924624  non-null values
votes                  924624  non-null values
keywords               924624  non-null values
lastdiffed             924509  non-null values
everconfirmed          924624  non-null values
reporter_accessible    924624  non-null values
cclist_accessible      924624  non-null values
estimated_time         924624  non-null values
remaining_time         924624  non-null values
deadline               0  non-null values
alias                  0  non-null values
found_in_product_id    924624  non-null values
found_in_version_id    924624  non-null values
found_in_phase_id      924624  non-null values
cf_type                924624  non-null values
cf_reported_by         924624  non-null values
cf_attempted           89622  non-null values
cf_failed              89587  non-null values
cf_public_summary      510799  non-null values
cf_doc_impact          924624  non-null values
cf_security            924624  non-null values
cf_build               327460  non-null values
cf_branch              614929  non-null values
cf_change              300612  non-null values
cf_test_id             12610  non-null values
cf_regression          924624  non-null values
cf_reviewer            924624  non-null values
cf_on_hold             924624  non-null values
cf_public_severity     924624  non-null values
cf_i18n_impact         924624  non-null values
cf_eta                 3910  non-null values
cf_bug_source          924624  non-null values
cf_viss                725  non-null values
dtypes: float64(5), int64(19), object(28)
```

- after 'convert_objects()':

```
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(5), int64(19), object(26)
```

- and putting the converted dataframe into hdfstore costs: **749.50 s** :)

  - it seems that reducing the number of 'object' dtypes is the key to decrease time costs
- and putting the converted dataframe into hdfstore with the param 'table' is true still returns that error

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.1.dev_6e2b6ea-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/pytables.pyc in create_axes(self, axes, obj, validate, nan_rep, data_columns, min_itemsize, **kwargs)
   2203                 raise
   2204             except (Exception), detail:
-> 2205                 raise Exception("cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->%s] %s" % (b.dtype.name, str(detail)))
   2206             j += 1
   2207 
Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->object] object of type 'datetime.datetime' has no len()
```

- I'm trying to put the dataframe without datetime columns

---

### Update 4

- There are 4 columns in mysql whose type is datetime:

  - creation_ts
  - delta_ts
  - lastdiffed
  - deadline

After calling the convert_objects():

- creation_ts:

```
Timestamp: 1998-05-06 21:27:00
```

- delta_ts:

```
Timestamp: 2012-05-09 14:41:41
```

- lastdiffed

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 9, 14, 41, 41)
```

- deadline is always None, no matter before or after calling 'convert_objects'

```
None
```

- putting the dataframe without column 'lastdiff' costs **691.75 s**
- when putting the dataframe without column 'lastdiff' and setting param 'table' equal to  True, I got an new error, :

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.1.dev_6e2b6ea-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/pytables.pyc in create_axes(self, axes, obj, validate, nan_rep, data_columns, min_itemsize, **kwargs)
   2203                 raise
   2204             except (Exception), detail:
-> 2205                 raise Exception("cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->%s] %s" % (b.dtype.name, str(detail)))
   2206             j += 1
   2207 

Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->object] object of type 'Decimal' has no len()
```

- the type of columns 'estimated_time', 'remaining_time', 'cf_viss' is 'decimal' in mysql

---

### Update 5

- I had transformed these 'decimal' type columns to 'float' type, by the code below:

```
no_diffed_converted_df_bugs.estimated_time = no_diffed_converted_df_bugs.estimated_time.map(float)
```

- and now, the time costs is **372.84 s**
- but the 'table' version putting still raised an error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.1.dev_6e2b6ea-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/pytables.pyc in create_axes(self, axes, obj, validate, nan_rep, data_columns, min_itemsize, **kwargs)
   2203                 raise
   2204             except (Exception), detail:
-> 2205                 raise Exception("cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->%s] %s" % (b.dtype.name, str(detail)))
   2206             j += 1
   2207 

Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->object] object of type 'datetime.date' has no len()
```

Comment: can you provide the code you are using, along with the pandas version? also pls post 'ptdump -av file.h5'; you are going to use table queries on just the indicies or specific columns? (e.g. give me sample queries that you will perform)

Comment: pls post the os as well..thxs

Comment: going to guess that you have a fair amount of string columns; this is broken on 0.10.0...update to 0.10.1-dev....on 64 bit linux 100 float columns + 20 string columns take 20s for me with 1M records

Comment: try the code i gave below (and use a different file); seems your .h5 file maybe somehow corrupted. the operation you are doing will actually be much faster than mine below but is not querayble at all - is that what you want?

Comment: and pls update to 0.10.1-dev

Comment: if possible can you also post a sample of a rows of data (or even ust show the dataframe summary, e.g. str(df)

Comment: also....pls print tables.__version__....reading your post again it seems that you may have an older PyTables (and/or hdf version)....you should have 2.3.1 at leas of PyTables

Comment: open the file like: `pd.HDFStore('extract_store.h5','w')`. this will overwrite the existing file, your file may be corrupted (or you can just delete the file first)

Comment: can you provide a sample row of your data? and a picture of the dataframe, e.g. str(df)

Comment: can you post a string represenation of a small slice of your data (.e.g. read_csv from a string or something). you have some datatypes that are being stringified I think). also try `df = df.convert_objects()`, and then try putting it (also try excluding your datetime columns and write it to test if that's the issue)

Comment: silly question, but you are measuring the put time separately, correct? (from the pull from sql)

Comment: another thing to try - write out the data to a csv, then read_csv - then try putting to HDFStore (also show the dtypes). in addition, u have lots of Nones in the columns, are these otherwise float columns?

Comment: see my update to the answer below....try to remove the datetime.date column (deadline?); hopefully you will be able to put this as a table then (and regular put should be much faster)...behind the scenese PyTables is pickling which explains the slowness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to make this faster?

1. use 'io.sql.read_frame' to load data from a sql db to a dataframe. Because the 'read_frame' will take care of the columns whose type is 'decimal' by turning them into float.
2. fill the missing data for each columns.
3. call the function 'DataFrame.convert_objects' before putting operation
4. if having string type columns in dateframe, use 'table' instead of 'storer'

store.put('key', df, table=True)

After doing these jobs, the performance of putting operation has a big improvement with the same data set:

```
CPU times: user 42.07 s, sys: 28.17 s, total: 70.24 s
Wall time: 98.97 s
```

---

Profile logs of the second test:

```
95984 function calls (95958 primitive calls) in 68.688 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      445   16.757    0.038   16.757    0.038 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
       19   16.250    0.855   16.250    0.855 {method '_append_records' of 'tables.tableExtension.Table' objects}
       16    7.958    0.497    7.958    0.497 {method 'astype' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
       19    6.533    0.344    6.533    0.344 {pandas.lib.create_hdf_rows_2d}
        4    6.284    1.571    6.388    1.597 {method '_fillCol' of 'tables.tableExtension.Row' objects}
       20    2.640    0.132    2.641    0.132 {pandas.lib.maybe_convert_objects}
        1    1.785    1.785    1.785    1.785 {pandas.lib.isnullobj}
        7    1.619    0.231    1.619    0.231 {method 'flatten' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
       11    1.059    0.096    1.059    0.096 {pandas.lib.infer_dtype}
        1    0.997    0.997   41.952   41.952 pytables.py:2468(write_data)
       19    0.985    0.052   40.590    2.136 pytables.py:2504(write_data_chunk)
        1    0.827    0.827   60.617   60.617 pytables.py:2433(write)
     1504    0.592    0.000    0.592    0.000 {method '_g_readSlice' of 'tables.hdf5Extension.Array' objects}
        4    0.534    0.133   13.676    3.419 pytables.py:1038(set_atom)
        1    0.528    0.528    0.528    0.528 {pandas.lib.max_len_string_array}
        4    0.441    0.110    0.571    0.143 internals.py:1409(_stack_arrays)
       35    0.358    0.010    0.358    0.010 {method 'copy' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    0.276    0.276    3.135    3.135 internals.py:208(fillna)
        5    0.263    0.053    2.054    0.411 common.py:128(_isnull_ndarraylike)
       48    0.253    0.005    0.253    0.005 {method '_append' of 'tables.hdf5Extension.Array' objects}
        4    0.240    0.060    1.500    0.375 internals.py:1400(_simple_blockify)
        1    0.234    0.234   12.145   12.145 pytables.py:1066(set_atom_string)
       28    0.225    0.008    0.225    0.008 {method '_createCArray' of 'tables.hdf5Extension.Array' objects}
       36    0.218    0.006    0.218    0.006 {method '_g_writeSlice' of 'tables.hdf5Extension.Array' objects}
     6110    0.155    0.000    0.155    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.empty}
        4    0.097    0.024    0.097    0.024 {method 'all' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        6    0.084    0.014    0.084    0.014 {tables.indexesExtension.keysort}
       18    0.084    0.005    0.084    0.005 {method '_g_close' of 'tables.hdf5Extension.Leaf' objects}
    11816    0.064    0.000    0.108    0.000 file.py:1036(_getNode)
       19    0.053    0.003    0.053    0.003 {method '_g_flush' of 'tables.hdf5Extension.Leaf' objects}
     1528    0.045    0.000    0.098    0.000 array.py:342(_interpret_indexing)
    11709    0.040    0.000    0.042    0.000 file.py:248(__getitem__)
        2    0.027    0.013    0.383    0.192 index.py:1099(get_neworder)
        1    0.018    0.018    0.018    0.018 {numpy.core.multiarray.putmask}
        4    0.013    0.003    0.017    0.004 index.py:607(final_idx32)
```

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty convinced your issue is related to type mapping of the actual types in DataFrames and to how they are stored by PyTables.

- Simple types (floats/ints/bools) that have a fixed represenation, these are mapped to fixed c-types
- Datetimes are handled if they can properly be converted (e.g. they have a dtype of 'datetime64[ns]', notably datetimes.date are NOT handled (NaN are a different story and depending on usage can cause the entire column type to be mishandled)
- Strings are mapped (in Storer objects to Object type, Table maps them to String types)
- Unicode are not handled
- all other types are handled as Object in Storers or an Exception is throw for Tables

What this means is that if you are doing a *put* to a Storer (a fixed-representation), then all of the non-mappable types will become Object, see this. **PyTables pickles these columns**. See the below reference for ObjectAtom

http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/libref/declarative_classes.html#the-atom-class-and-its-descendants

Table will raise on an invalid type (I should provide a better error message here). I think I will also provide a warning if you try to store a type that is mapped to ObjectAtom (for performance reasons).

To force some types try some of these:

```
import pandas as pd

# convert None to nan (its currently Object)
# converts to float64 (or type of other objs)
x = pd.Series([None])
x = x.where(pd.notnull(x)).convert_objects()

# convert datetime like with embeded nans to datetime64[ns]
df['foo'] = pd.Series(df['foo'].values, dtype = 'M8[ns]')
```

Heres a sample on 64-bit linux (file is 1M rows, about 1 GB in size on disk)

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: pd.__version__
Out[3]: '0.10.1.dev'

In [3]: import tables

In [4]: tables.__version__
Out[4]: '2.3.1'

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000 * 1000, 100), index=range(int(
   ...: 1000 * 1000)), columns=['E%03d' % i for i in xrange(100)])

In [5]: for x in range(20):
   ...:     df['String%03d' % x] = 'string%03d' % x

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Columns: 120 entries, E000 to String019
dtypes: float64(100), object(20)

# storer put (cannot query) 
In [9]: def test_put():
   ...:     store = pd.HDFStore('test_put.h5','w')
   ...:     store['df'] = df
   ...:     store.close()

In [10]: %timeit test_put()
1 loops, best of 3: 7.65 s per loop

# table put (can query)
In [7]: def test_put():
      ....:     store = pd.HDFStore('test_put.h5','w')
      ....:     store.put('df',df,table=True)
      ....:     store.close()


In [8]: %timeit test_put()
1 loops, best of 3: 21.4 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff.
I think i have got the point, now i'm fighting against tons of None value, the 'fillna' method is very helpful.
Once i finished this ,i would paste my solution here as well as how fast the putting operation would be.

Comment: I added 1) better error messages on table creation for types that we are rejecting, and 2) a PerformanceWarning when you try to put columns that are going to be pickled. - you can update to my repository and give a try if you want. https://github.com/jreback/pandas/tree/pytables_update6

Comment: Maybe a nice trick/slightly dirty way to get around the unicode issues is to convert unicode columns into string columns with the "xmlcharrefreplace" option; later on you can translate this back into unicode if you want to.

Comment: PyTables 3.0.0 handles unicode by default in py3; you can store unicode in py2 as a Fixed store: the only restriction is on Tables (and u can always do some sort of hybrid - eg do your searching in Tables then load the Unicode and just index into it)