# Better solution when dealing with the missing data for those dataframe objs exported from related db

Tags: python, pandas

Few days ago, I posted a question about ["how to make pandas HDFStore 'put' operation faster"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355151/how-to-make-pandas-hdfstore-put-operation-faster/14474667), and thanks for Jeff's answer, I find a more efficient way to extract data from db and store them into a hdf5 file.

But by this way, I have to  fill the missing data for every single columns  according to their types, and do these work on every single table(In most cases, This work is repetitive). Otherwise, the None object in the dataframe would cause a performance problem when i put the dataframes into a hdf5 file.

Is there a better way for doing this job?

I just read [this issue "ENH: sql to provided NaN/NaT conversions"](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2754)

- will NaT work with other types? (except datetime64)
- Can i use it replace all None objects in the dataframe without worrying about performance problem when storing dataframe into a hdf5 file?

### UPDATE1

- pd.**version**: 0.10.1
- I'm using np.nan to fill the missing data now.But i met two problems.

  - The columns which have both np.nan and datetime.datetime objs can not be converted to 'datetime64[ns]' type and will raise Excetions when put them into hdfstore.

```
    In [155]: len(df_bugs.lastdiffed[df_bugs.lastdiffed.isnull()])
    Out[155]: 150

    In [156]: len(df_bugs.lastdiffed)
    Out[156]: 1003387

    In [158]: df_bugs.lastdiffed.astype(df_bugs.creation_ts.dtype)

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
    ----> 1 df_bugs.lastdiffed.astype(df_bugs.creation_ts.dtype)

    /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/series.pyc in astype(self, dtype)
        777         See numpy.ndarray.astype
        778         """
    --> 779         casted = com._astype_nansafe(self.values, dtype)
        780         return self._constructor(casted, index=self.index, name=self.name)
        781 

    /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/common.pyc in _astype_nansafe(arr, dtype)
       1047     elif arr.dtype == np.object_ and np.issubdtype(dtype.type, np.integer):
       1048         # work around NumPy brokenness, #1987
    -> 1049         return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
       1050 
       1051     return arr.astype(dtype)

    /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.astype_intsafe (pandas/lib.c:11886)()

    /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/lib.so in util.set_value_at (pandas/lib.c:44436)()

    ValueError: Must be a datetime.date or datetime.datetime object


        # df_bugs_sample1 = df_bugs.ix[:10000]
    In [147]: %prun store.put('df_bugs_sample1', df_bugs_sample1, table=True)

    /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/pytables.pyc in put(self, key, value, table, append, **kwargs)
        456             table
        457         """
    --> 458         self._write_to_group(key, value, table=table, append=append, **kwargs)
        459 
        460     def remove(self, key, where=None, start=None, stop=None):

    /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/pytables.pyc in _write_to_group(self, key, value, index, table, append, complib, **kwargs)
        786             raise ValueError('Compression not supported on non-table')
        787 
    --> 788         s.write(obj = value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
        789         if s.is_table and index:
        790             s.create_index(columns = index)

    /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/pytables.pyc in write(self, obj, axes, append, complib, complevel, fletcher32, min_itemsize, chunksize, expectedrows, **kwargs)
       2489         # create the axes
       2490         self.create_axes(axes=axes, obj=obj, validate=append,
    -> 2491                          min_itemsize=min_itemsize, **kwargs)
       2492 
       2493         if not self.is_exists:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/pytables.pyc in create_axes(self, axes, obj, validate, nan_rep, data_columns, min_itemsize, **kwargs)
       2252                 raise
       2253             except (Exception), detail:
    -> 2254                 raise Exception("cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->%s,items->%s] %s" % (b.dtype.name, b.items, str(detail)))
       2255             j += 1
       2256 

    Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->object,items->Index([bug_file_loc, bug_severity, bug_status, cf_branch, cf_bug_source, cf_eta, cf_public_severity, cf_public_summary, cf_regression, cf_reported_by, cf_type, guest_op_sys, host_op_sys, keywords, lastdiffed, priority, rep_platform, resolution, short_desc, status_whiteboard, target_milestone], dtype=object)] object of type 'datetime.datetime' has no len()
```

- And the other df seems can not be ***completely*** put into a dataframe, as the sample below, the number of entries are ***13742515***, but after i put the dataframe into a hdfstore and get it out, the number of entries changes to ***1041998***.That's weird~

```
    In [123]:df_bugs_activity
    Out[123]:
    
    Int64Index: 13742515 entries, 0 to 13742514
    Data columns:
    added        13111366  non-null values
    attach_id    1041998  non-null values
    bug_id       13742515  non-null values
    bug_when     13742515  non-null values
    fieldid      13742515  non-null values
    id           13742515  non-null values
    removed      13612258  non-null values
    who          13742515  non-null values
    dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(4), object(2)


    In [121]: %time store.put('df_bugs_activity2', df_bugs_activity, table=True)

    CPU times: user 35.31 s, sys: 4.23 s, total: 39.54 s
    Wall time: 39.65 s

    In [122]: %time store.get('df_bugs_activity2')

    CPU times: user 7.56 s, sys: 0.26 s, total: 7.82 s
    Wall time: 7.84 s
    Out[122]:
    
    Int64Index: 1041998 entries, 2012 to 13354656
    Data columns:
    added        1041981  non-null values
    attach_id    1041998  non-null values
    bug_id       1041998  non-null values
    bug_when     1041998  non-null values
    fieldid      1041998  non-null values
    id           1041998  non-null values
    removed      1041991  non-null values
    who          1041998  non-null values
    dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(4), object(2)
```

### Update 2

- the code for creating the dataframe:

```
    def grab_data(table_name, size_of_page=20000):
        '''
        Grab data from a db table

        size_of_page: the second argument of sql's limit subclass
        '''
        cur.execute('select count(*) from %s' % table_name)
        records_number = cur.fetchone()[0]
        loop_number = records_number / size_of_page + 1
        print '****\nStart Grab %s\n****\nrecords_number: %s\nloop_number: %s' % (table_name, records_number, loop_number)

        start_position = 0
        df = DataFrame()  # WARNING: this dataframe object will contain all records of a table, so BE CAREFUL of the MEMORY USAGE!

        for i in range(0, loop_number):
            sql_export = 'select * from %s limit %s, %s' % (table_name, start_position, size_of_page)
            df = df.append(psql.read_frame(sql_export, conn), verify_integrity=False, ignore_index=True)

            start_position += size_of_page
            print 'start_position: %s' % start_position

        return df

    df_bugs = grab_data('bugs')
    df_bugs = df_bugs.fillna(np.nan)
    df_bugs = df_bugs.convert_objects()
```

- The sturcture of df_bugs:

```
Int64Index: 1003387 entries, 0 to 1003386
Data columns:
alias                  0  non-null values
assigned_to            1003387  non-null values
bug_file_loc           498160  non-null values
bug_id                 1003387  non-null values
bug_severity           1003387  non-null values
bug_status             1003387  non-null values
category_id            1003387  non-null values
cclist_accessible      1003387  non-null values
cf_attempted           102160  non-null values
cf_branch              691834  non-null values
cf_bug_source          1003387  non-null values
cf_build               357920  non-null values
cf_change              324933  non-null values
cf_doc_impact          1003387  non-null values
cf_eta                 7223  non-null values
cf_failed              102123  non-null values
cf_i18n_impact         1003387  non-null values
cf_on_hold             1003387  non-null values
cf_public_severity     1003387  non-null values
cf_public_summary      587944  non-null values
cf_regression          1003387  non-null values
cf_reported_by         1003387  non-null values
cf_reviewer            1003387  non-null values
cf_security            1003387  non-null values
cf_test_id             13475  non-null values
cf_type                1003387  non-null values
cf_viss                1423  non-null values
component_id           1003387  non-null values
creation_ts            1003387  non-null values
deadline               0  non-null values
delta_ts               1003387  non-null values
estimated_time         1003387  non-null values
everconfirmed          1003387  non-null values
found_in_phase_id      1003387  non-null values
found_in_product_id    1003387  non-null values
found_in_version_id    1003387  non-null values
guest_op_sys           1003387  non-null values
host_op_sys            1003387  non-null values
keywords               1003387  non-null values
lastdiffed             1003237  non-null values
priority               1003387  non-null values
product_id             1003387  non-null values
qa_contact             1003387  non-null values
remaining_time         1003387  non-null values
rep_platform           1003387  non-null values
reporter               1003387  non-null values
reporter_accessible    1003387  non-null values
resolution             1003387  non-null values
short_desc             1003387  non-null values
status_whiteboard      1003387  non-null values
target_milestone       1003387  non-null values
votes                  1003387  non-null values
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(10), int64(19), object(21)
```

### Update 3

- write to csv and read from csv:

```
    In [184]: df_bugs.to_csv('df_bugs.sv')
    In [185]: df_bugs_from_scv = pd.read_csv('df_bugs.sv')
    In [186]: df_bugs_from_scv
    Out[186]:
    
    Int64Index: 1003387 entries, 0 to 1003386
    Data columns:
    Unnamed: 0             1003387  non-null values
    alias                  0  non-null values
    assigned_to            1003387  non-null values
    bug_file_loc           0  non-null values
    bug_id                 1003387  non-null values
    bug_severity           1003387  non-null values
    bug_status             1003387  non-null values
    category_id            1003387  non-null values
    cclist_accessible      1003387  non-null values
    cf_attempted           102160  non-null values
    cf_branch              345133  non-null values
    cf_bug_source          1003387  non-null values
    cf_build               357920  non-null values
    cf_change              324933  non-null values
    cf_doc_impact          1003387  non-null values
    cf_eta                 7223  non-null values
    cf_failed              102123  non-null values
    cf_i18n_impact         1003387  non-null values
    cf_on_hold             1003387  non-null values
    cf_public_severity     1003387  non-null values
    cf_public_summary      588  non-null values
    cf_regression          1003387  non-null values
    cf_reported_by         1003387  non-null values
    cf_reviewer            1003387  non-null values
    cf_security            1003387  non-null values
    cf_test_id             13475  non-null values
    cf_type                1003387  non-null values
    cf_viss                1423  non-null values
    component_id           1003387  non-null values
    creation_ts            1003387  non-null values
    deadline               0  non-null values
    delta_ts               1003387  non-null values
    estimated_time         1003387  non-null values
    everconfirmed          1003387  non-null values
    found_in_phase_id      1003387  non-null values
    found_in_product_id    1003387  non-null values
    found_in_version_id    1003387  non-null values
    guest_op_sys           805088  non-null values
    host_op_sys            806344  non-null values
    keywords               532941  non-null values
    lastdiffed             1003237  non-null values
    priority               1003387  non-null values
    product_id             1003387  non-null values
    qa_contact             1003387  non-null values
    remaining_time         1003387  non-null values
    rep_platform           424213  non-null values
    reporter               1003387  non-null values
    reporter_accessible    1003387  non-null values
    resolution             922282  non-null values
    short_desc             1003287  non-null values
    status_whiteboard      0  non-null values
    target_milestone       423276  non-null values
    votes                  1003387  non-null values
    dtypes: float64(12), int64(20), object(21)
```

Comment: use np.nan for missing values; u don't have to 'fill them in', just put your data, all others are missing by definition, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html

Comment: pls post a small sample of your data, how your are reading it, and how you are storing it

Comment: Thanks jeff~ i just update my question. Could you explain the meaning of 'all others are missing by definition'? i can't get your point.

Comment: I've read the release notes of pandas 0.10.1, and not found any changes on dealing the missing data when putting dataframe into hdfstore.

Comment: for your first issue, you cannot mix np.nan and datetimes at all, this makes them 'object' which won't work. You need to properly convert to datetime64[ns], I cannot see EXACLTY what you are doing, pls post your creation code (with a small example data), same for you second example

Comment: * Sorry jeff, I didn't make it clear.  
 * What i'm doing is pretty simple: Loading a table into a Dataframe, and put the dataframe into a hdfstore.

Comment: No, I get what you are doing, the problem is with creating the dataframe in the first place, and how you are 'filling' it; pls show that code and some data. you are reading an sql table, yes? THAT is the problem, you need to do some conversions, but w/o seeing that data (after it is loaded), I cannot help you

Comment: do this, read in from sql, WRITE it out to a csv file, then read in again, and post that

Comment: read this section on DataTypes in http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#notes-caveats

Comment: looking at your csv write/read it appears that your datetimes went away (prob because the missing values are not correct). I would s suggest you try this with 0.11-dev; datetimes should work better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer myself, and thanks jeff's help.

First of all, the second problem("a df seems can not be **completely** put into a dataframe") in the update 1 has been [fixed](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3012).

And, the biggest problem I met are dealing with the columns which have both python's **datetime** obj and **None** obj in them. Fortunately,  since the 0.11-dev, pandas provide a more [convenient way](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#datatypes). I used the codes below in my project, and i have added comments for some lines, hope it can help others :)

```python
cur.execute('select * from table_name')
result = cur.fetchall()

# For details: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description
db_description = cur.description
columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in db_description]

# As the pandas' doc said, `coerce_float`: Attempt to convert values to non-string, non-numeric objects (like decimal.Decimal) to floating point
df = DataFrame(result, columns=columns, coerce_float=True)

# dealing the missing data
for column_name in df.columns:
    # Currently, calling function `fillna(np.nan) on a `datetime64[ns]` column will cause an exception
    if df[column_name].dtype.str != '<M8[ns]':
        df[column_name].fillna(np.nan)

# convert the type of columns which both have np.nan and datetime obj from 'object' to 'datetime64[ns]'(short as'<M8[ns]')
# find the table columns whose type is Date or Datetime
column_name_type_tuple = [column[:2] for column in db_description if column[1] in (10, 12)]
# check whose type is 'object'
columns_need_conv = [column_name for column_name, column_type in column_name_type_tuple if str(df[column_name].dtype) == 'object']

# do the type converting
for column_name in columns_need_conv:
    df[column_name] = Series(df[column_name].values, dtype='M8[ns]')

df = df.convert_objects()
```

After this, the df should be suitable for storing in h5 file, and not need 'pickle' anymore.

ps:

some profile:
complib: 'lzo', complevel: 1
table1, 7,810,561 records with 2 int cols and 1 datetime col, the putting operation costs **49s**

table2, 1,008,794 records with 4 datetime cols, 4 float64 cols, 19 int cols, 24 object(string) cols, the putting operation costs **170s**