# Put operation hangs

Tags: pandas, hdf5, pytables, pickle

I'm exploring whether Python, and specifically Pandas with HDF5, would be an appropriate environment to do some time-series modelling ... the upshot of which is that I have next to no experience (yet!) in any of these so please excuse any stupid questions.

To cut to the chase I've been having some problems even doing the most basic inserts of dummy data into an HDF5 file. I was following the supplied code in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14370190/2688892) but when I get to writing in the storer format the code execution hangs. I've not tried the table format yet, I'd like to get this working first. I'm running the following file.

**test_put.py:**

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Tracer; debugStart = Tracer()
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tables

print "Pandas version: " + pd.__version__ # 0.11.0
print "NumPy version: " + np.__version__ # 1.7.1
print "Tables version: " + tables.__version__ # 2.4.0

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000 * 1000, 100),
                  index=range(int(1000 * 1000)),
                  columns=['E%03d' % i for i in xrange(100)])

for x in range(20):
    df['String%03d' % x] = 'string%03d' % x

def test_storer_put():
    store = pd.HDFStore('test_put.h5','w')
    debugStart()
    store['df'] = df
    store.close()

def test_table_put():
    store = pd.HDFStore('test_put.h5','w')
    store.put('df',df,table=True)
    store.close()

test_storer_put()
```

using ipdb in ipython I've got a call stack to the hanging line as pasted below. This line is calling cPickle, which I assume is some sort of compiled library. I can't step into this line (using 's') any further so am out of ideas as to what the problem is.

```
  ~/test_put.py(20)test_storer_put()
     18     store = pd.HDFStore('test_put.h5','w')
     19     debugStart()
---> 20     store['df'] = df
     21     store.close()
     22

  ~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py(241)__setitem__()
    239
    240     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
--> 241         self.put(key, value)
    242
    243     def __delitem__(self, key):

  ~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py(536)put()
    534             table
    535         """
--> 536         self._write_to_group(key, value, table=table, append=append, **kwargs)
    537
    538     def remove(self, key, where=None, start=None, stop=None):

  ~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py(871)_write_to_group()
    869             raise ValueError('Compression not supported on non-table')
    870
--> 871         s.write(obj = value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
    872         if s.is_table and index:
    873             s.create_index(columns = index)

  ~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py(2005)write()
   2003             blk = data.blocks[i]
   2004             # I have no idea why, but writing values before items fixed #2299
-> 2005             self.write_array('block%d_values' % i, blk.values)
   2006             self.write_index('block%d_items' % i, blk.items)
   2007

  ~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py(1799)write_array()
   1797             vlarr = self._handle.createVLArray(self.group, key,
   1798                                               _tables().ObjectAtom())
-> 1799             vlarr.append(value)
   1800         elif value.dtype.type == np.datetime64:
   1801             self._handle.createArray(self.group, key, value.view('i8'))

  ~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/vlarray.py(462)append()
    460         atom = self.atom
    461         if not hasattr(atom, 'size'):  # it is a pseudo-atom
--> 462             sequence = atom.toarray(sequence)
    463             statom = atom.base
    464         else:

  ~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/atom.py(1000)toarray()
    998
    999     def toarray(self, object_):
-> 1000         buffer_ = self._tobuffer(object_)
   1001         array = numpy.ndarray( buffer=buffer_, dtype=self.base.dtype,
   1002                                shape=len(buffer_) )

> ~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/atom.py(1112)_tobuffer()
   1110
   1111     def _tobuffer(self, object_):
-> 1112         return cPickle.dumps(object_, cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
   1113
   1114     def fromarray(self, array):
```

The arguments in scope at the hanging line are:

```
ipdb> a
self = ObjectAtom()
object_ = [['string000' 'string001' 'string002' ..., 'string017' 'string018'
  'string019']
 ['string000' 'string001' 'string002' ..., 'string017' 'string018'
  'string019']
 ['string000' 'string001' 'string002' ..., 'string017' 'string018'
  'string019']
 ...,
 ['string000' 'string001' 'string002' ..., 'string017' 'string018'
  'string019']
 ['string000' 'string001' 'string002' ..., 'string017' 'string018'
  'string019']
 ['string000' 'string001' 'string002' ..., 'string017' 'string018'
  'string019']]
```

In stepping through the code I've noticed that `BlockManagerStorer.write()` method, which is about half way up the call stack above, is looping through 2 sets of data blocks (lines 2002 to 2006). The first loop runs fine and it is the second loop that hangs. Further the `GenericStorer.write_array()` method that is then called in the next stack down has `value.dtype.type == 'numpy.float64'` in the first pass but `value.dtype.type == 'numpy.object'` in the second pass leading to a different branch on line 1785 of io/pytables.py being taken. ***EDIT:*** The first pass is writing a ~800 Meg file so it appears to be most of the expected output file.

Lastly in case this is architecture / software flavor related. I'm running the following:

*Machine*: Virtual Machine, 1 CPU, 4Gb RAM, 64 bit
*OS*: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)
*Software*: Python, Pandas, PyTables, etc installed via anaconda from a couple of days ago. Hopefully relevant version numbers were printed in the script above (as comments!) but let me know if others are appropriate.

TIA for any help
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your exact configuration, with the exception I use debian/squeeze

```
OS: Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012 x86_64
In [4]: print "Pandas version: " + pd.__version__ # 0.11.0
Pandas version: 0.11.0

In [5]: print "NumPy version: " + np.__version__ # 1.7.1
NumPy version: 1.7.1

In [6]: print "Tables version: " + tables.__version__ # 2.4.0
Tables version: 2.4.0
```

On a `storer`, string-like objects (e.g. the index/columns Index) are pickled (as opposed to `tables` where the types are determined and the are written in a native format). Your backtrace indicates it failed in the pickle, which is weird; possibly there is some limitation on red hat linux, possibly a bug in PyTables 2.4 (or pandas). I cannot reproduce that.

I would try upgrading to pandas 0.12, PyTables 3.0.0 and see if it persists.

In any event, `Table` format should work just fine for you and offers a number of advantages in any event, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#table-format)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. You are right that the Table format does work in my simple example, so step 1 solved.

Comment: Any instructions for how to update to latest versions? RHEL repositories don't even support pandas (that I can see), which is why I used Anaconda

Comment: Also I'm having other issues on writing data frames with multi-indexes and other more complex examples. I've got other work to attend to so will raise in another post ... most likely next week

Comment: ``pip install pandas==0.12``; ``pip install tables==3.0.0``

Comment: Wow that's easy ... but I'm behind a corporate firewall that blocks anything that moves. I'll need to get a hole punched through it. Am I correct in saying pip is trying to connect to https://pypi.python.org/simple/?